# HTML dynamic data-ng-click functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the functionality of data-ng-click(Button is being created dynamically) but it is not working, could any one help me in this?

```
var table = document.getElementById("dashboard");
for( var i = 0; i < $scope.namesOfMembers.length; i++ ){
   var row = table.insertRow(2);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
   var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
   var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
   cell1.innerHTML = namesOfMembers[i];
   cell2.innerHTML = paidOrNot[i];
   cell3.innerHTML=amountPaid[i];

   var amtBox = '<input type="text" size="20" style="height: 23px" data-ng-model="amountBox" />';
   angular.element(cell4).append((amtBox));

   var updBtn = '<input id="updateAmount" type="button" value="UPDATE" data-ng-click="showDashBoard()" />';
   angular.element(cell4).append((updBtn));
```

Comment: Is this code of angular app?

Comment: If you are trying to dynamically append elements with angular directives, then you have to use `$compile`

Comment: @Hardik This code is angular js App

Comment: @varunagarwal can u show piece of code to how to use $compile

Comment: Here is an example - https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx. Basically you do a `$compile(<HTML ELEMENT>, scope)` which returns an element which can be appended wherever you want.

Comment: @varunagarwal I tried the $compile https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/07/using-compile-in-angular.aspx but it is not working. i.e the button itself is not showing in the UI

Answer (score 0):

here's a semi working example of how to get the button click working

https://plnkr.co/edit/B7luwA4q49SyY7AjRDbT?p=preview

The line in question is:

```
  $compile(table)($scope);
```

There will be other things you need to do, based on the assumption that each input box is used to update that particular members amount, you'll need to modify their models in order to keep them separate.

If you're doing this to handle the three different arrays maintaining all the data, would it not be better to massage the data into something like:

```
{ name: 'name', isPaid: true, payment: 25.00 }
enter code here
```

so you can take advantage of ng-repeat, ordering and filtering?

Comment: Hi @kendavidson in the example u given me https://plnkr.co/edit/B7luwA4q49SyY7AjRDbT?p=preview i want to get {pal,true,30} when i click the respective update button. i.e when i click the update button i should get the respective 3 values in an array could u please help in that

Comment: Hi @kendavidson in the example u have given https://plnkr.co/edit/B7luwA4q49SyY7AjRDbT?p=preview  when i click on the update button i want to get the respective details to an object or array could u please help me in this

Comment: Hey. There are a few ways to do it. But with the least number of changes to what you have just add a "track by $index" to the repeat. Then pass the $index into function call. That way you can do [namesOfMembers[$index],...] to build the array. Again though it might be easier to build objects with the three arrays either on the server or client so you can take advantage of other things.  I'm on my phone now but if no one else helps out I'll jump on my laptop tomorrow.

Comment: Here ya go, I modified the first controller and added a second to give you an idea of what might make things a little easier.  There are still some more things I'd probably do to it, but both should get you going. https://plnkr.co/edit/xlMYGv4I1s9ZRJKV8Rpl?p=preview